# How to adjust drop-down menu item in <ul> with the use of css columns property?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using 2-column navigation menu in my website. with the use of following css

```
.column-menu {
  columns: 2;
  -webkit-columns: 2;
  -moz-columns: 2;
  width: 378px;
 }
```

i am getting this output:

[image]

This is perfect as i want it to be. But, when i open the drop-down menu, it becomes like this:

[image]

is there anyway to get the output as displayed in the following screenshot:

[image]

Here is my full html:

```css
.column-menu {
  columns: 2;
  -webkit-columns: 2;
  -moz-columns: 2;
  width: 378px;
}
.column-menu li a {
  padding: 0 15px;
  font: 13px/38px"Kanit", sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.column-menu li a:hover,
.column-menu li a:focus {
  background: none;
}
.column-menu li.active a {
  color: #333;
}
.column-menu li.open a {
  background: none;
}
.column-menu li.open a:hover,
.column-menu li.open a:focus {
  background: none;
}
.column-menu li.open a span {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.column-menu li.open ul {
  background: none;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav column-menu black-bg">
  <li class="active dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Home <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Home Option 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Home Option 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Home Option 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Home Option 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Home Option 5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Home Option 6</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">categories</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">archives</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">faq</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I believe your submenu is using `position: absolute`. Try `position: relative`

Comment: Please add your code to the question. No one can help you accurately without seeing what you have

Comment: I think with css `column-count` can't do this. You will need to use 2 `<ul>` for this. Place the left menu items in left `<ul>` and the right items in the right one.

Comment: Just increase the height of the menu :)

Comment: @MuhammadUsman i am using this code for wordpress where i cannot manage 2 <ul> .

Comment: Tricky CSS question should almost always be in a jsfiddle. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: add a working fiddle and we might be able to help

Comment: The submenu ist not position: absolute. It is static and because of that, the the css-columns are distributing the whole content. To be honest i don't think there is any way, to change this work the way you want. You have to edit the markup or you have to use another way than css-columns.

Comment: @VictorRadu here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/cLec82sg/

Answer (score 0):

**This is may help you...read this code fully and work it and sure you will get it..**

**HTML :**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
<div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
</div>
<!--/.navbar-header-->

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">One Column <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Two Column <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-column columns-2">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Something else here that's extra long so we can see how it looks</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Three Column <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-column columns-3">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!--/.navbar-collapse-->
```

**CSS :**
The noteworthy CSS here is the min-width properties for the .columns-2 and .columns-3 ul‘s. These are necessary to keep the menu from doing some wild stuff… but, there are certainly other approaches. I also added some CSS for the .multi-column-dropdown ul‘s so they match Bootstrap’s styling.

*Note: be sure to include bootstrap.css in your head as well.

```
.dropdown-menu {
min-width: 200px;
}
.dropdown-menu.columns-2 {
min-width: 400px;
}
.dropdown-menu.columns-3 {
min-width: 600px;
}
.dropdown-menu li a {
padding: 5px 15px;
font-weight: 300;
}
.multi-column-dropdown {
list-style: none;
}
.multi-column-dropdown li a {
display: block;
clear: both;
line-height: 1.428571429;
color: #333;
white-space: normal;
}
.multi-column-dropdown li a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
color: #262626;
background-color: #f5f5f5;
}


@media (max-width: 767px) {
.dropdown-menu.multi-column {
    min-width: 240px !important;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
}
```

**JS:**
Just be sure to include jQuery and Bootstrap in your page (preferably towards the bottom, right before the closing body tag).

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

first use this code in rough manner and you will get an idea